# Conversion to set of custom collections class returns empty set in Python

Tags: python, collections, set

I've recently written my own OrderedSet implementation since I had problems with the publicly available ordered/sorted set implementations. The class uses a dict proxy object in the background and mostly forwards operations. I implemented all (in my opinion) relevant methods, incl. `__iter__`, and calls like `list(myset)` work as expected.

However, the call `set(myset)` *always* returns empty sets.

Here's the full code of OrderedSet:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional, Iterable, Set, AbstractSet, Union, Iterator, Any, Dict

T = TypeVar("T")
S = TypeVar("S")


class OrderedSet(Generic[T], Set[T]):
    def __init__(self, base: Optional[Union[Dict[T, None], Iterable[T]]] = None):
        super().__init__()

        self.the_dict: Dict[T, None]
        if not base:
            self.the_dict = {}
        elif isinstance(base, dict):
            self.the_dict = base
        else:
            self.the_dict = dict.fromkeys(base)

    def __eq__(self, o: object) -> bool:
        return isinstance(o, OrderedSet) and list(self.the_dict) == list(o.the_dict)

    def __ne__(self, o: object) -> bool:
        return not self.__eq__(o)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{" + ", ".join(list(map(str, self.the_dict))) + "}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"OrderedSet({repr(self.the_dict)})"

    def add(self, element: T) -> None:
        self.the_dict = {**self.the_dict, **{element: None}}

    def clear(self) -> None:
        self.the_dict.clear()

    def copy(self) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        return OrderedSet(self.the_dict.copy())

    def difference(self, s: Iterable[Any]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        return OrderedSet({e: None for e in self.the_dict if e not in s})

    def difference_update(self, s: Iterable[Any]) -> None:
        self.the_dict = {e: None for e in self.the_dict if e not in s}

    def discard(self, element: T) -> None:
        del self.the_dict[element]

    def intersection(self, s: Iterable[Any]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        return OrderedSet({e: None for e in self.the_dict if e in s})

    def intersection_update(self, s: Iterable[Any]) -> None:
        self.the_dict = {e: None for e in self.the_dict if e in s}

    def isdisjoint(self, s: Iterable[Any]) -> bool:
        return self.the_dict.keys().isdisjoint(s)

    def issubset(self, s: Iterable[Any]) -> bool:
        return set(iter(self)).issubset(iter(s))

    def issuperset(self, s: Iterable[Any]) -> bool:
        return set(iter(self)).issuperset(iter(s))

    def pop(self) -> T:
        items = list(self.the_dict)
        result = items.pop()
        self.the_dict = dict.fromkeys(items)
        return result

    def remove(self, element: T) -> None:
        del self.the_dict[element]

    def symmetric_difference(self, s: Iterable[T]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        return OrderedSet(
            dict.fromkeys([e for e in self.the_dict if e not in s] +
                          [e for e in s if e not in self.the_dict]))

    def symmetric_difference_update(self, s: Iterable[T]) -> None:
        self.the_dict = self.symmetric_difference(s).the_dict

    def union(self, s: Iterable[T]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        return OrderedSet({**self.the_dict, **dict.fromkeys(s)})

    def update(self, s: Iterable[T]) -> None:
        self.the_dict = self.union(s).the_dict

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.the_dict)

    def __contains__(self, o: object) -> bool:
        return o in self.the_dict

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[T]:
        return iter(self.the_dict)

    def __and__(self, s: AbstractSet[object]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        return self.intersection(s)

    def __iand__(self, s: AbstractSet[object]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        result = self.intersection(s)
        self.the_dict = result.the_dict
        return result

    def __or__(self, s: AbstractSet[S]) -> 'OrderedSet[Union[T, S]]':
        return self.union(s)

    def __ior__(self, s: AbstractSet[S]) -> 'OrderedSet[Union[T, S]]':
        result = self.union(s)
        self.the_dict = result.the_dict
        return result

    def __sub__(self, s: AbstractSet[Optional[T]]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        return self.difference(s)

    def __isub__(self, s: AbstractSet[Optional[T]]) -> 'OrderedSet[T]':
        result = self.difference(s)
        self.the_dict = result.the_dict
        return result

    def __xor__(self, s: AbstractSet[S]) -> 'OrderedSet[Union[T, S]]':
        return self.symmetric_difference(s)

    def __ixor__(self, s: AbstractSet[S]) -> 'OrderedSet[Union[T, S]]':
        result = self.symmetric_difference(s)
        self.the_dict = result.the_dict
        return result

    def __le__(self, s: AbstractSet[object]) -> bool:
        return self.issubset(s)

    def __lt__(self, s: AbstractSet[object]) -> bool:
        return self.issubset(s) and len(self) < len(s)

    def __ge__(self, s: AbstractSet[object]) -> bool:
        return set(iter(self)) >= set(iter(s))

    def __gt__(self, s: AbstractSet[object]) -> bool:
        return set(iter(self)) > set(iter(s))
```

And here some example calls:

```py
>>> from orderedset import OrderedSet
>>> s = OrderedSet([3, 1, 2])
>>> s
OrderedSet({3: None, 1: None, 2: None})
>>> list(s)
[3, 1, 2]
>>> set(s)
set()
```

Does anybody have an idea what's going on here? The `set()` function seems to be implemented in lengthy C code, which I don't understand well enough to deduce anything. It seems, though, that `__iter__` is called for conversion to `list`, but not to `set`...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fascinating... >_< I've tried to tinker with `__getattribute__` and stuff to see which internal func is called, got nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python `3.9` or above

Your class should be inheriting from [`collections.abc.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) instead of [`typing.Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=abstractset#typing.Set)(which has been deprecated anyway)

```
from collections.abc import Set
...
class OrderedSet(Generic[T], Set[T]):
    ...

obj = OrderedSet()
obj.add(1)
obj.add(2)
obj.add(3)
print(set(obj)) # {1,2,3}
```

### Python `3.8` or lower

Before 3.9, using generics with `collections.abc.Set` was not possible. Inheriting from [`AbstractSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=abstractset#typing.AbstractSet) solves the problem.

```
from typing import Generic, AbstractSet
...
class OrderedSet(Generic[T], AbstractSet[T]):
    ...
```

Comment: When applying this change, I get the error `TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable`. Did you try your fix out? Did it work for you?

Comment: ...it seams that you have to omit the `[T]` in `Set[T]` when using `collections.abc`.

Comment: What's your python version? If you're using an older version of python, try inheriting from `AbstractSet` instead. [Here's](https://ideone.com/bgJVIR) a version of the code which runs on python 3.7

Comment: However, as you'll note, the docs specifically say "Deprecated since version 3.9: `collections.abc.Set` now supports []. See PEP 585 and Generic Alias Type." for [`AbstractSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=abstractset#typing.AbstractSet)

Comment: Good point, I was running Python 3.8 for whatever reason. Probably an outdated venv after switching to Python 3.10 globally. And indeed, inheriting from collections.abc.Set also solves the problem, as does inheriting from any *abstract* base class (so, not the standard `set` class or aliases like typing.Set).

Comment: Selected this answer, since calling `super().__init__(self.the_dict.keys())` creates different problems, in particular I have to forward all other calls as to `discard` etc.

Comment: Edited the answer to include this. Probably should've been there in the first place. `3.9` is still quite new for a lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `super` or otherwise it would be an empty set

```
    def __init__(self, base: Optional[Union[Dict[T, None], Iterable[T]]] = None):
        self.the_dict: Dict[T, None]
        if not base:
            self.the_dict = {}
        elif isinstance(base, dict):
            self.the_dict = base
        else:
            self.the_dict = dict.fromkeys(base)
        super().__init__(self.the_dict.keys())
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Very interesting. Inheriting from collections.abc.Set (other answer) did not make a difference for me; rather, I received a TypeError.

Comment: Actually, what also works is simply *not* inheriting from Set! Otherwise, I also have to forward all state-changing requests, like to discard(), also to the super class (or set() does not work), which imposes additional overhead. When I remove the inheritance from Set, iter() is called when invoking set().